# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, apache2, python-3.8

Estoy tratando de pasar a un servidor en Ubuntu mi aplicación, y me manda los siguientes errores.

**Configuración Apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin comovoy@comovoy.com
    ServerName proyecto
    DocumentRoot /var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoCoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoCoyApp/static/
    Alias /media /var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoCoyenv/ComoVoy/media/
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    # WSGIDaemonProcess ComoVoy python-path=/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv:/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    # WSGIDaemonProcess ComoVoy python-path=/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    WSGIDaemonProcess ComoVoy python-path=/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup ComoVoy
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoVoyWeb/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoVoyWeb>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo wsgi.py
**wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "ComoVoyWeb.settings"
#prevenimos UnicodeEncodeError
os.environ.setdefault("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8")
os.environ.setdefault("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
#activamos nuestro virtualenv
activate_this = '/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Estructura del proyecto**

```
proyecto
|- ComoVoyenv
|  |- bin
|  |- ComoVoy
|  |  |- ComoVoyApp (Django App)
|  |  |- ComoVoyWeb
|  |  |  |- ...
|  |  |  |- wsgi.py
|  |  |- manage.py
|  |- lib
```

Al momento de intentar acceder a al aplicación desde la IP del servidor me manda los siguientes errores.
**Log de errores cuando intento acceder a aplicación**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=119080): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoVoyWeb/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=119080): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoVoyWeb/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/ComoVoy/ComoVoyWeb/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/var/www/proyecto/ComoVoy/ComoVoyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

He seguido unos tutoriales pero aún así me siguen saliendo errores, estoy usando Apache 2.4.41 y Python 3.8, instalé mod_wsgi a través de pip3.

He probado cosas que he encontrado en la red, pero aun así no he podido resolver este problema.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con esto y decirme qué estoy haciendo mal, o que me falta, o si tengo mal alguna configuración?

Gracias.

Comment: verifica bien el nombre del modulo que importas y también verifica que sea la forma correcta de importarlo, mira la documentación para saber si algo cambió

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría ser que es una versión vieja de mod_wsgi, puedes probar esto:

Ve a esta pagina y descarga la ultima versión de mod_wsgi (mod_wsgi 4.8.0):
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.tar.gz

En la terminal de ubuntu muevete a donde descargaste el archivo, desempaqueta el archivo asi:

```
tar xvfz mod_wsgi-4.7.1.tar.gz
```

Configura el codigo fuente ejecutando en la terminal:

```
./configure
```

Compila e instala ejecutando:

```
make
make install
```

Y por ultimo reinicia el servidor de apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Otra posible solución es que intentes reinstalar el paquete de psycopg:

```
pip3 uninstall psycopg2
pip3 install psycopg2
```